# Detecting File Download Completion Status

Tags: python, django

I would just like to ask if it's possible for me to check the status of a file (csv file) download in Django .
I have a template page with a button, which when clicked, opens a 'Save As' dialog box for downloading a file from the server (file content is retrieved from db).  after the download is complete i want to update my DB with its status (if download complete status = Downloaded ,if abort status = aborted , if Cancel Status= Canceled  . How can i do this ?

Comment: Check attached link ... u have to customize it according to your problem. [click here](http://markmail.org/message/kmrpk7w3h56tidxs#query:jquery%20ajax%20download%20progress+page:1+mid:kmrpk7w3h56tidxs+state:results)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you could check filesize at two timepoints and then compare the filesize. For sure if the download is pausing for some reason, this solution is not very good.

Comment: I guess the problem with this is if the download fails (or you lose internet connection for a bit), it'll shows as download complete.